# tomcat 7 undeploy fails dues log4j.properties

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, log4j, undeploy

This error is quite puzzling. In my webapps, I have the log4j.properties in WEB-IF/classes as per recommendation.

When I deploy from eclipse, I do a stop on the webapp, undeploy, and then deploy. Strangely enough, 8 out of 10 times I get the following error on undeploy- 
build.xml:526: FAIL - Unable to delete [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\punch]. The continued presence of this file may cause problems.

The only file remaining under my webapp is the WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties. Everything else is deleted.

I cannot manually delete the file or the webapp folder either. I have to stop Tomcat service, delete the folder and then restart.

Is there any solution for this?

Thanks.

Here is my remove task in build.xml

```
<target name="remove"
 description="Remove application on servlet container">

<stop url="${manager.url}"
     username="${manager.username}"
     password="${manager.password}"
         path="${app.path}"/>

<undeploy url="${manager.url}"
     username="${manager.username}"
     password="${manager.password}"
         path="${app.path}"/>

</target>
```

Comment: Tomcat has some file locking issues.  I've seen this many times, but I've never found a solution.

Comment: Tomcat does not have any known file locking issues. Plenty of third party libraries do have issues and Tomcat jumps through a number of hoops to work around known issues where it can. The solution is to identify what is holding the lock on the file via a profiler and then figure out how to get it to release. That may require a bug report against the library to provide a shutdown() type method.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the file is opened for reading. You need to at least shutdown your app. That can easily be done with [PsiProbe](http://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/).

Comment: I do a stop and then undeploy. The frustrating part is that it works some times but not most.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call LogManager.shutdown() in the contextDestroyed() method of a ServletContextListener. That should ensure that log4j doesn't have the file open.

Comment: That will be the right way to do it and will be tech debt, got a  workaround for now ...

Comment: We have this problem sometimes. Happens even with the .shutdown() in the servlets destroy method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my work around:

I created another target to copy the war to Tomcat's webapp directory.

```
<target name="copywar" depends="dist">
    <copy file="${dist.home}/${app.name}.war" todir="${catalina.home}/webapps" />
</target>
```

I also made sure that Tomcat could redeploy with this in server.xml

```
<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

This works just fine. Thanks for your help folks.